# How do I apply style for parent div and their hidden child div also?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The application is more of single page navigation with div manipulation. Based on the Previous/Next button it will display the section accordingly. Now, I have to generate a preview page for the filled form data. My thought was to clone all divs and replace the input fields with read-only. Here is my div structure which was cloned already.

**Solution Looking for** : Enable each div style display into "inline-block"

[image]

**Code tried:**

```
function confirmationPage() {
        //1
        $(".pgePreview").closest('div').children().css('display', 'inline-block');
        //2
        $("#pgePreview div").each(function (e) {
            if (e != 0) {
                $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $(".pgePreview div").css('display','inline-block') will work, as you want each div to be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("#parent div").each(function (e) {
        if (e != 0) {
            $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="parent">
        <div>
            <div style="display:none; border: 1px solid; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
            <div style="display:none; border: 1px solid; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
            <div style="display:none; border: 1px solid; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
            <div style="display:none; border: 1px solid; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
            <div style="display:none; border: 1px solid; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am sorry. It did not worked.Do i need to remove the class?

Comment: My bad.I have not included the clone command. Brilliant. It worked.

Comment: it happens, :) getting errors means something is cooking great